# The control with ID 'Timer1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Hi im writing some visual basic code and i decided to add a timer into the application that i am making. So my code is all fine with no red lines so, i press run and then it starts to open in the browser. But then i get this message: Server Error in '/' Application.

The control with ID 'Timer1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The control with ID 'Timer1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

Comment: Just add the ScriptManager at the top of the page... I find it interesting that you want to add a Timer to a asp.net application.

Comment: im not going to anymore

Comment: but can you help fix my other problem